# unidentified when alerting array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

When I run this it alerts unidentified whenever `worldgeny == 400` and i do not know why.
If i alert `worldgeny` in the same place it alerts `NaN`. I may have not explained this very well. if you are confused just ask.
My code is messy I know this is just a test for me personally
Thanks in advance

```
var addy;
var worldgeny = parseInt(200);
var mul5 = parseInt(0);
var endhole;
var holegen;
var sizeh = 30;
var sizew = 30;
var savey = [];

function cworld() {
    mul5++;
    posX++;
    canvasContext.drawImage(imageGround, posX, worldgeny, 1, 400);
        if(mul5 % 30 == 0){
            if(worldgeny==400){
                endhole = mul5/30;
                endhole = endhole - 1;
                worldgeny=savey[endhole];
                alert(savey[endhole])
            }
            addy = parseInt(Math.floor((Math.random()*30)-17));
            holegen = parseInt(Math.floor((Math.random()*5)));
            worldgeny += addy;
            if(holegen==1){
                worldgeny = 400;
            }
            savey.push(worldgeny);
        }
    }
setInterval(cworld, 1);
```

Comment: Ack!  Indentation please!

Comment: All I can tell you is that it's trying to access an array index that doesnt exist.

Comment: @tymeJV But the index is defined I have checked

Comment: It doesn't matter if the index is defined - what matters is that `savey` actually contains an element *at* that index.

Comment: @DesertIvy it does as you can see at the 'savey.push(worldgeny);' part of the code

Comment: That line is run after your `alert()`, when `savey` has no elements.

Comment: @DesertIvy Im not arguing im just confused but my function loops if you look at setInterval also it checks the previous index rather than the one coming up

Answer (score 2):

```
var savey = [];
```

This is an empty array.

```
alert(savey[endhole])
```

No matter what `endhole` is, this evaluates to `undefined`, since `savey.length` is `0`.

```
savey.push(worldgeny);
```

This actually adds elements to `savey`. Until you do this, every time you try to reference an element of that array, it will return `undefined`.

Furthermore, make sure `endhole` is a valid index. If `savey` has a length of `N`, make sure `endhole` is between `0` and `N-1`.

**EDIT**: It looks like the real culprit is your assignment of `endhole`. First you say `endhole = mul5/30`, but `mul5` is `0`, so now `endhole` is `0`. Right after this, you decrement it, leaving the value of `endhole` to be `-1`, which is an invalid index in the array.

I'm not sure what logic you want to implement to fix this, but your index must be `0` or greater. Referencing an array's index of `-1` will always result in `undefined`.

Comment: But it is always undefined even after i do that since it loops

Comment: See my edit concerning your `endhole` index. It should always be between `0` and the length of your array minus one.

Comment: Ok thank you but when i alert 'endhole' it is between the lenght of my array minus 1 so it still does no work

Comment: Perhaps you are pushing `undefined` into your array. Check that variable just in case. And just as a tip, you will find it easier to debug if you use `console.log()` (or any similar method) to output your variables. Better yet, use a JS debugger like Firebug, or Chrome's built-in Developer Tools (access both with F12). You'll save yourself the grief of clicking through `alert` dialogs. :)

Comment: See my edit. I think your logic in computing your `endhole` index variable is wonky.

Comment: but mul5 increases by one every run of the function and its atleast 30 by the time it runs that code which would equal endhole to 1 and then at minimum it would then be 0. and 0 (which is minimum) doesnt make an array undefined

Comment: It does indeed increase by one every time you call the function, but your index is out of bounds. Please check it. Insert this line *in place* of `alert(savey[endhole])`: `console.log("mul5 = " + mul5, "endhole = " + endhole, "savey.length = " + savey.length);`. You will clearly see that `endhole` is the same as `savey.length`, which is out of bounds for that array.